# Timezone Array That Factors Daylight Savings

Tags: php, datetime

So I copied an array of timezones from another stackoverflow article. I need GMT offset numbers (the array name) to match the user friendly string, as I am using it to make a dropdown box for a user to select their timezone. I already made a script that will take the GMT offset and automatically convert a timestring on a schedule to the user's selected timezone based off the GMT offset.

```
$timezoneTable = array(
"-12" => "Eniwetok, Kwajalein",
"-11" => "Midway Island, Samoa",
"-10" => "Hawaii",
"-9" => "Alaska",
"-8" => "Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)",
"-7" => "Mountain Time (US &amp; Canada)",
"-6" => "Central Time (US &amp; Canada), Mexico City",
"-5" => "Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada), Bogota, Lima",
"-4" => "Atlantic Time (Canada), Caracas, La Paz",
"-3.5" => "Newfoundland",
"-3" => "Brazil, Buenos Aires, Georgetown",
"-2" => "Mid-Atlantic",
"-1" => "Azores, Cape Verde Islands",
"0" => "Western Europe Time, London, Lisbon, Casablanca",
"1" => "Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris",
"2" => "Kaliningrad, South Africa",
"3" => "Baghdad, Riyadh, Moscow, St. Petersburg",
"3.5" => "Tehran",
"4" => "Abu Dhabi, Muscat, Baku, Tbilisi",
"4.5" => "Kabul",
"5" => "Ekaterinburg, Islamabad, Karachi, Tashkent",
"5.5" => "Bombay, Calcutta, Madras, New Delhi",
"6" => "Almaty, Dhaka, Colombo",
"7" => "Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta",
"8" => "Beijing, Perth, Singapore, Hong Kong",
"9" => "Tokyo, Seoul, Osaka, Sapporo, Yakutsk",
"9.5" => "Adelaide, Darwin",
"10" => "Eastern Australia, Guam, Vladivostok",
"11" => "Magadan, Solomon Islands, New Caledonia",
"12" => "Auckland, Wellington, Fiji, Kamchatka"
```

);

The problem is, for example. Is that array isn't accurate for daylights savings. For example, right now Central time is -5 GMT.

How can an array be pulled that factors in daylight savings?

Comment: DST depends on the timezone and the actual datetime, it's not static. Aka: you can't use a static array...

Comment: Is there an API or something I can pull from to get an updated timezone database with GMT offsets?